# Realizar función php desde un icono de font-awesome

Tags: php, html, font-awesome, onclick

¡Muy buenas a tod@s!

Les planteo mi problema: tengo un icono de font awesome y desde él, lo que quiero es cerrar sesión (hacer un session_destroy()). Lo he intentado de mil maneras pero no encuentro la solución.

Les dejo mi código para ver si me podéis ayudar. Espero vuestra respuesta.

Un saludo.

*php*

```
<?php 
include_once('./core/funciones.php');

                        if (isset($_SESSION['ncompleto'])){
                        ?><span class="n_perfil"><?php echo $_SESSION['ncompleto'] ?></span>
                        <i onclick="cerrar_sesion()" class="fa fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
                        <?php
                    }else{
```

*funcion (ubicada en la carpeta core, en el archivo de funciones.php)*

```
function cerrar_sesion(){
    session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: session_destroy(); sirve en javascritp? que no tendrias que enviarlo a un archivo php

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil si podría, pero el session_destroy() es código php, ¿cómo podría meterlo en una función de js?

Comment: eso mismo te digoestas pasando con onclick es una funcion js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haci debes enviarlo a tu funcion a tu archivo php

```
    <a href="<?php echo URL;?>/login.php?$variable='desconectar'>" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Cerrar Sesión</a>

    <a href="<?php echo URL;?>/login.php?usuario=$usuario&contrasena=contrasena&variable='conectar'?>" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">iniciar sesion</a>

    en tu funcion lo recibes como lo tienes
if($variable="desconectar"){
    function cerrar_sesion(){
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: URL/index.php");
    }
}else{
        function conectar($usuario,$contrasena){
       // tu codigo para iniciar sesion 
         header(location :  DIRECCIONALO A LA PAGINA QUE QUIERAS);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo crearía un fichero .php con `session_destroy()` y lo ejecutaría con la función `onclick`.

Fichero donde está el icono:

```
<a href="./desconectar.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a>
```

Fichero desconectar.php:

```
session_destroy();
```

Para que el usuario no se quede en tu desconectar.php puedes redireccionarlo con:

```
header("Location: ../index.php");
```

Comment: Ya lo había pensado, pero ya suficientes ficheros tengo como para meter otro más jajaja. Aún así muchas gracias por tu aportación!

Comment: pues crea funciones desconectar(), conectar(); validarConexion()  etc... en un archivo y le pasas el parametro por get a la funcion que vayas a utilizar

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil ¿podriás ponerme un ejemplo de como se haría eso?

Comment: ya modifique mi codigo ahi te lo puse